# Naming multiple strings with an incremented count

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

I want to name an multiple string with an incremented count
example: String str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, and so on
This isn't the exact circumstance for it, but it is the simplest example i can thing of

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
        String str[i] = " "; // i want to name the String str1,str2,str3
    }
}
```

This is the basic for loop i created to try to accomplish this, but it didn't work. How else can I go about naming multiple String with a loop

to clarify and add more in case it helps; i have a class:

```
public Player(String playerName, boolean isDealer){}
```

&& i have the method for creating each player

```
  int amount; //amount of players

  for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    if(i == dealer){continue;}
    System.out.println("What is the name of player " + i + "?");
    playerName = IO.readString();
            isDealer = false;
        Player player.valueAt(i); //creating player1,player2,player3,playeri

        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using an Array? That way, you can say: 'Str[0]', 'Str[1]', 'Str[2]'...

Comment: Array is the best way to go in such circumstances. If you absolutely need that sort of naming, you need to create it using another program and copy and paste the output.

Comment: As you are new I wanted to point out that when you feel that you have got your answer, you have to mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement can not done by java At least but you have other options like :

#### 1.  Array

```
String[] str = new String[no-of-element];
for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++){
  str[i] = "str"+i; 
}
```

#### 2. Collection

you can use [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Strings won't work that way you need to consider creating array of strings instead

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed that is not possible in JAVA. But here are some solutions:

***First Way:*** Use `Map` with `Key` as your generated name like str1, str2.... and `value` as your string object. And then when you want to use them, you can use `get(name_of_str)` to get the object you are looking for.

***Second Way:*** otherwise. But if you still want to do it, try using `Metaprogramming`.

Comment: use `Map<String,Player>` and that should solve your purpose. `String` is the player name and `Player` is the instance you created.